# performance issues using UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

Union in the oracle query is causing a lot of FTS (full table scans) and high row count any better way i can rewrite this query ?

```
            SELECT
                            tab1.a1,
                            tab1.a2 ,
                            tab2.b1,
                            tab2.b2


            FROM tab1 ,tab2
                    where tab1.aid = tab2.aid
                    and tab1.bid = tab2.bid
            UNION 
            SELECT
                            tab1.a1,
                            tab1.a2,
                            tab3.c1,
                            tab3.c2
            FROM tab1 ,tab3
                    where tab1.cid = tab3.cid
                    and tab1.bid =tab3.bid;
```

Explain plan pretty much looks like this..

```
                 | Id  | Operation                     | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |  1845K|    61M|       |   120K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
                 |   1 |  UNION-ALL                    |       |       |       |            |          |
                 |   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |  1719K|    57M|       | 98522   (2)| 00:00:04 |
                 |   3 |    SORT JOIN                  |  1761K|    25M|    94M| 30984   (1)| 00:00:02 |
                 |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         |  1761K|    25M|       | 21911   (1)| 00:00:01 |
                 |*  5 |    SORT JOIN                  |  1882K|    35M|   115M| 67538   (2)| 00:00:03 |
                 |   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         |  1882K|    35M|       | 56061   (2)| 00:00:03 |
                 |   7 |   NESTED LOOPS                |   126K|  3699K|       | 22186   (1)| 00:00:01 |
                 |   8 |    NESTED LOOPS               |   126K|  3699K|       | 22186   (1)| 00:00:01 |
                 |   9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         |   126K|  1726K|       |  3232   (2)| 00:00:01 |
```

Index are on (tab1 (aid,bid), tab2(aid,bid) , tab3(cid,bid))

Comment: Your query has no `WHERE` clause. So it's all tab1 records and possibly many, many tab2 and tab3 records involved. So full table scans seem the best approach to read the tables, rather than muddle through indexes only to end up with most records, though. Your query is obfuscating its real task though. user5480949's answer shows a query that is much clearer.

Comment: You are using a join syntax that we used in the 1980s. Oracle was late to adopt it, but still that was about 2001! You should not use it anymore. Use proper ANSI joins instead, e.g. `from tab1 inner join tab2 on tab1.aid = tab2.aid and tab1.bid = tab2.bid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.a1, t.a2  
FROM tab1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tab2 t2
              WHERE t.aid = t2.aid
              AND t.bid = t2.bid)
OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM tab3 t3
           WHERE t.cid = t3.cid
           AND t.bid =t3.bid)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the straight-forward way to write the query.

Comment: @user5480949 , thanks for the query, works briliantly and gives the correct output, i somehow missed to add the tab2 and tab3 columns in the query and not able to figure out, where to add in the query you gave, request to please help me with an edit of the query.

Comment: @anudeepks: With the tab2 and tab3 columns selected, your new query is completely different from what you had before. So you can make this a new request altogether.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner thank you ill create a new request